# Searching for entries between two dates in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, datetime-format

I have a collection `"received"` in which documents contain a embedded filed which consists of year and week details. For example:

```
"YearANDWeek" : {
    "Year" : 1908,
    "Week" : 6
}
```

If I want to get data between year 1956 and week 23 to year 2000 and week 40 what query I need to use? I can use `$gte` and `$lt` but there is conflict between weeks.

Comment: How about writing your predicate like this: 
`(1956 == YearANDWeek.Year && 23 <= YearANDWeek.Week) || (2000 == YeahANDWeek.Year && 40 > YearANDWeek.Week) || (1957 <= YearANDWeek.Year && 1999 >= YearANDWeek.Year)`

Comment: Can you show your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following query.

```
db.received.find({$where:"((this.YearANDWeek.Year > 1956 && this.YearANDWeek.Year < 2000) || (this.YearANDWeek.Year == 1956 && this.YearANDWeek.Week >= 23) || (this.YearANDWeek.Year == 2000 && this.YearANDWeek.Week <= 40))"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I this you can try this

```
db.recieved.find({$where:"((this.YearANDWeek.Year >= 1956 && this.YearANDWeek.Week >= 6) || (this.YearANDWeek.Year < 2000 && this.YearANDWeek.Year > 2000 && this.YearANDWeek.Week < 40)) && (this.YearANDWeek.Year >= 1956 && this.YearANDWeek.Year < 2000)"})
```